# Is there any difference between Dictionary.Keys.Contains(key) and Dictionary.ContainsKey(key)

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose:

```
Dictionary<Guid, MyClass> dict;
```

Is there any difference [between](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481488(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
dict.Keys.Contains(key)
```

[and](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
dict.ContainsKey(key)
```

I thought there was no difference, but I am not sure now.

Comment: right, I didn't notice `Contains` is implemented differently in KeyCollection. by the way first approach create an extra reference for KeyCollection, you shouldn't bother but IMO only use `Keys` property when you actually need it.

Comment: Either method should be used sparingly. A good proportion of the time you think you need to use it (i.e. when you want to know whether the key exists, and what the value is **for** that key), you should likely use `TryGetValue` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two methods are guaranteed to return the same `true`/`false` value.

According to [reference implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs), `dict.Keys.Contains(key)` delegates to `dict.ContainsKey(key)`:

```
bool ICollection<TKey>.Contains(TKey item){
    return dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
}
```

This method is part of `KeyCollection` class. Its `dictionary` field refers to the `Dictionary` object that owns the `KeyCollection` returned by `Keys` property.

Answer (score 2):

The first line retrieves the keys collection before searching for the key, while the second line searches the dictionary's keys directly avoiding an extra step.

According to the documentation for the [Dictionary.Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) property, accessing the collection is a constant time operation and does not involve creating a copy of the entire set of dictionary keys. Thus there appears to be little difference between the two operations aside from the additional step of retrieving the keys collection before searching for the key.

All things being equal, I would personally prefer the second version because it skips the extra step and conveys your intent more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary is optimized for looking up keys.

With `dict.ContainsKey(key)` you would be sure to use that optimized search.

When you use `dict.Keys.Contains(key)` you are more dependent on the implementation. The naive route would first get an `IEnumerable<TKey>` and then do the (linear) lookup. The actual library class might be smarter but you would always have to look up the source to be sure.

Comment: It explicitly states [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481488(v=vs.110).aspx) *"This method is an O(1) operation."* so there is no need to fear of a naive implementation, it is documented.

Comment: Yes, but that's just one implementation. I couldn't find the same statement for SortedDictionary for example.